# Bind callback to ReactJS state from DynamoDB DocumentClient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get the hang of passing the returned objects out of AWS' DynamoDB Document Client module to set state with react.

My issue, I cant pull the data out of the method (my previous attempts at using callback failed) and cant (apparently) setState inside of the method.

I have view a fair amount of documentation and can manipulate state from an inline object (it is returned as an object with the docClient) but this one doesn't play nice.

Below is my basic starting point, with a return as a placeholder but I need an example, for i am teh simple.

I would appreciate any help and/or admonishment here. Thanks all.

```
export default class AwsReadFunction extends React.Component {

 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    elss: "chicken"
  };
 }

 render(){
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
  var table = "Movies";
  var year = 1944;
  var title = "Lifeboat";
  var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
      "year": year,
      "title": title
    }
  };

  var goog = docClient.get(params,
    function(err, data){
      // I think this is where I need help with scope and callback
      return data.Item.title;
    }
  );

  setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({
    elss: goog
   });
  }, 2000)

  return (
   <div>
    {this.state.elss}
    <List />
   </div>
  );
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't perform asynchronous actions, or *any* actions that modify the state for that matter, in `render()`. That's because `render()` gets called whenever the state changes, and if you change the state in `render()` you might end up with an endless loop. A better place would be `componentDidMount()`.

Also, you should set the state in the callback to `docClient.get()`, because only when that gets called will you be able to access the downloaded data.

Try this:

```
export default class AwsReadFunction extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={ elss: "chicken" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    var table = "Movies";
    var year = 1944;
    var title = "Lifeboat";
    var params = {
      TableName: table,
      Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
      }
    };

    var goog = docClient.get(params, (err, data) => {
      // TODO: handle `err`
      this.setState({ elss : data.Item.title });
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.elss}
        <List />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I noticed looping in my attempts. That makes perfect sense now.